# How to get the radio button values from mongodb to the edit/update form? (Angular | Express | Nodejs | MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, radio-button

Adding data to the database using this crud application successfully works. but when i'm trying edit a particular record (a document in mongodb), all the other fields get automatically filled with existing data in mongodb, but the radio button doesn't get selected according to the value stored in mongodb.

**employee.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s5">
            <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
              <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee._id">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter full name" required>
                  <label>Name :
                    <label class="red-text">*</label>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="position" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.position" placeholder="Eg : Snr. Developer">
                  <label>Position :</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="office" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.office" placeholder="Enter office location">
                  <label>Office :</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="salary" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.salary" placeholder="Salary per annum">
                  <label>Salary :</label>
                </div>
              </div>

                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="gender" type="radio" value="1" [(ngModel)]="gender" />
                    <span>Male</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="gender" type="radio" value="2" [(ngModel)]="gender"/>
                    <span>Female</span>
                  </label>
                </p>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <button class="btn btn-custom right" type="button" (click)="resetForm(employeeForm)">Reset</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-custom right" type="submit" [disabled]="!employeeForm.valid">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col s7">
              <table class="responsive-table highlight">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Position</th>
                      <th>Office</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tr *ngFor="let emp of employeeService.employees">
                    <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.position}}</td>
                    <td>{{emp.office}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="action-btn" (click)="onEdit(emp)">
                          <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="action-btn" (click)="onDelete(emp._id,employeeForm)">
                          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                        </a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**employee.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee.model';

declare var M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css'],
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.refreshEmployeeList();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form)
      form.reset();
    this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
      _id: "",
      name: "",
      position: "",
      office: "",
      salary: null,
      gender: null
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id == "") {
      this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
        M.toast({ html: 'Saved successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
    else {
      this.employeeService.putEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
        M.toast({ html: 'Updated successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }

  refreshEmployeeList() {
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeList().subscribe((res) => {
      this.employeeService.employees = res as Employee[];
    });
  }

  onEdit(emp: Employee) {
    this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = emp;
  }

  onDelete(_id: string, form: NgForm) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
      this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(_id).subscribe((res) => {
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
        this.resetForm(form);
        M.toast({ html: 'Deleted successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }

}
```

**employeeController.js**

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

var { Employee } = require('../models/employee');

// => localhost:3000/employees/
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Employee.find((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(docs); }
        else { console.log('Error in Retriving Employees :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    Employee.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Retriving Employee :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var emp = new Employee({
        name: req.body.name,
        position: req.body.position,
        office: req.body.office,
        salary: req.body.salary,
        gender: req.body.gender,
    });
    emp.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Employee Save :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});

router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    var emp = {
        name: req.body.name,
        position: req.body.position,
        office: req.body.office,
        salary: req.body.salary,
        gender: req.body.gender,

    };
    Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: emp }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Employee Update :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    Employee.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Employee Delete :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is the picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3D2q.jpg) of the current status of the edit form. I need this radio button to get selected according to the value stored in mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
As you're using Angular, why don't you use Angular Material? MatRadioButton has a simple implementation. 

    <mat-radio-group
      class="example-radio-group"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedGender">
      <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let gender of listOfGenders" [value]="gender.displayValue">
        {{gender.displayName}}
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>

You can create a list of gender objects with displayName and displayValue properties in the ts file. Store the displayValue with the User Object in MongoDB. When you retrieve the data, assign the stored value to the selectedGender property.
```

Comment: Actually this is a group project and others have already begun to do their parts using materialize css. so it's too late change the framework now. that's why i need the answer based on materialize.

Comment: One thing that you could do is, create radio buttons using javascript(jquery). add a checked property to the one that is already been selected.